# elasticsearch java client update script with params

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using this script to update a document:

```
     UpdateResponse response = client.prepareUpdate("index","type","id")
         .setScript("ctx._source.activity_entry = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(\" {\\\"last_activity_refresh_time\\\": 777 }\");"
                    ,ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
         .get();
```

and it works.

I'd like to use params instead of specifying into the script the values to update, but if I use this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("param", "{last_activity_refresh_time: 777 }");
UpdateResponse response = client.prepareUpdate("index","type","id")
            .setScriptParams(params)
            .setScript("ctx._source.activity_entry = param;", ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
```

it returns me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.StrictDynamicMappingException: mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [activity_entry] within [activity_entry] is not allowed
```

Whatever the value I put in the param, like this:

```
params.put("param", "adfhskjfh");
```

I always obtain the same error, as if the problem was not the value but in the mechanism behind it.

I'm using elastic 1.5.2. Any hint on how to make it work?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was wrong, the missing call to the JsonSlurper for the param:

```
.setScript("ctx._source.activity_entry = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(param);",ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
```